# Reading Complex Matrix From Text File

Tags: c

I am having a lot of trouble trying to read a complex matrix from a text file in C. The format of the text file is of the form `(%le%+lej)`. The test matrix used is:

```
 (0.000000000000000000e+00+0.000000000000000000e+00j)  (0.000000000000000000e+00+1.000000000000000056e-01j)  (0.000000000000000000e+00+2.000000000000000111e-01j)  (0.000000000000000000e+00+3.000000000000000444e-01j)
 (1.100000000000000089e+00+0.000000000000000000e+00j)  (1.100000000000000089e+00+1.000000000000000056e-01j)  (1.100000000000000089e+00+2.000000000000000111e-01j)  (1.100000000000000089e+00+3.000000000000000444e-01j)
 (2.200000000000000178e+00+0.000000000000000000e+00j)  (2.200000000000000178e+00+1.000000000000000056e-01j)  (2.200000000000000178e+00+2.000000000000000111e-01j)  (2.200000000000000178e+00+3.000000000000000444e-01j)
```

I have spent nearly two days just trying to get this working. So I would like a simple and easy to debug solution if such a thing exists.

My simplified attempt:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    char fname[] = "test_matrix.dat";
    int m = 3;
    int n = 4;
    complex double * matrix = calloc(m * n, sizeof(complex double));
    FILE * ifile = fopen(fname, "r");
    int i, j, info;
    double zreal, zimag;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            info = fscanf(ifile, "(%le%lej)", &zreal, &zimag);
            // The following doesn't work either.
            // info = fscanf(ifile, "(%le", &zreal);
            // info += fscanf(ifile, "%lej)", &zimag);
            if(info != 2)
            {
                fclose(ifile);
                fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input format, info = %d\n", info);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            *(matrix + i + j*m) = zreal + I*zimag;
            // printf("%d ", info); This gives all zeroes
            printf("%6.1e%+7.1ej ", zreal, zimag);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(ifile);
    free(matrix);
    return(0);
}
```

I have also tried not putting the extra formatting things in the `fscanf`, instead I tried looping `fgetc` till I read `(` and then doing two `fscanf`s, but it quickly became too complicated and hard to debug, still haven't been able to get that working. So any assistance will be appreciated.

EDIT: This is irrelevant to the problem, but just to clarify I am using column major format because it has to be used with blas/lapack later on.

Comment: What does `fscanf()` return from the call?  What do you mean with _doesn't work_?  What happens in your code?  Just check the returned value from `fscanf()` (which should be the actual number of real values successfully scanned) and probably that will give you a hint on what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fscanf` format is not correct :

```
info = fscanf(ifile, " (%le+%lej)", &zreal, &zimag);
```

Comment: Would this work with `1.2232e-02-3.4324e-04`? The sign in the middle can be plus or minus.

Comment: The format was correct, the `+` in the middle will be parsed as the sign of the second number.

Comment: Since the input in the question starts with a space character, the format string must be `" (%le+%lej)"`, not `"(%le+%lej) "`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, that actually worked. Finally! Thanks a lot! Could you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @adch99: I have edited this answer with my fixed format string, so you can accept it, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you requested it, I'd like to add to [Fryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6475652/fryz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74927714/16835308) by providing a complete working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *filename = "test_matrix.dat";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Could not open file");
        return 1;
    }

    const size_t nrows = 3;
    const size_t ncols = 4;

    complex double *matrix = malloc(nrows * ncols * sizeof(*matrix));
    if (!matrix) {
        printf("Internal error\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    double zreal, zimag;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
            if (fscanf(file, " (%le+%lej)", &zreal, &zimag) != 2) {
                printf("%zu::%zu: Wrong format\n", i, j);
                continue;
            }

            matrix[i*ncols+j] = zreal + I * zimag;
            printf("(%.18le+%1.18lej) ", zreal, zimag);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(matrix);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Output:

```
(0.000000000000000000e+00+0.000000000000000000e+00j) (0.000000000000000000e+00+1.000000000000000056e-01j) (0.000000000000000000e+00+2.000000000000000111e-01j) (0.000000000000000000e+00+3.000000000000000444e-01j)
(1.100000000000000089e+00+0.000000000000000000e+00j) (1.100000000000000089e+00+1.000000000000000056e-01j) (1.100000000000000089e+00+2.000000000000000111e-01j) (1.100000000000000089e+00+3.000000000000000444e-01j)
(2.200000000000000178e+00+0.000000000000000000e+00j) (2.200000000000000178e+00+1.000000000000000056e-01j) (2.200000000000000178e+00+2.000000000000000111e-01j) (2.200000000000000178e+00+3.000000000000000444e-01j)
```

Few things to note:

- Always check the return value of C standard library functions.
- Use `const` when a variable's value will not be changed.
- The appropriate type for indices is `size_t`, not `int`.
- Close your file handles and free your allocated memory when you are done with them.

Comment: Should be `matrix[i*ncols+j]`. Current code results in a buffer overflow.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom That was a typo. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works successfully on my computer with the input below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double x, y;
    int res;
    while ((res = fscanf(stdin, "(%lg%lgj)", &x, &y)) == 2) {
        printf("(%g, %g)", x, y);
    }
    printf("res == %d\n", res);
}
```

and the following input:

```
$ a.out
(3-5j)(2-8j)(-6+3j)                    <-- input
(3, -5)(2, -8)(-6, 3)res == 0          <-- output
$ _
```

As you probably guess, as soon as I press the return key, the input does not match, and I get three valid complex numbers read, and after that nothing is matched (`fscanf()` gets a `\n` char, and reads nothing, returning 0 to the while loop.  I printed the result of the function to see why it is failing.  Between the inputs you should handle the whitespace yourself (to distinguish also when you scan a `\n`) is my suggestion.

a better format would be to scanf two numbers for the matrix dimensions, then `rows*cols` pairs of numbers, for the matrix contents, all of them separated by any kind of whitespace.  E.g.

```
2 2
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
```

that will result in identity matrix read from the input file.

For a more elaborate reader, you will need to get help from `flex(1)` and/or `bison(1)` tools, that allows you to handle whitespace and even comments or nested parenthesis!!! :)  Those tools were written to help you in the full parsing of elaborate languages, like C or pascal.